# Strange JQuery behavior

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2017

I'm playing with Jquery and here is the code:
(Vs2017, Web Form application,jquery-3.3.1) Seen using both IE11 and Chrome

look at the picture below: 
I have an if statement which clearly is false. But code inside this if runs!

```
if(1>5)
{
....
}
```

Please look at screenshot:

[image]

could this be a VS2017 bug?

Sadly I see lots of downvotes( which I cannot care less about them ), but what is really sad no one explain the reason for downvote:

1: I tried to provide complete info in the question if you need more info to let me know.

2: I provided a simple example which shows the issue

Also, a colleague of mine says a simple JavaScript alert function behaves

intermittently in VS2017 and he did not have this issue in VS2015.

==================================================================

FYI I used the Exact code in VS 2015 (IE11 And chrome) code works as expected!

I'm going to report this as a to the Microsoft.

I do suggest for the good of Stackoverflow do not close such an informative posting. This may save lots of time for others.

Comment: I mean... you can run the code and see for yourself. This is in no way related to jquery.

Comment: You set your variable to true before the condition....

Comment: Which browser are you using? I always debug JavaScript in the browser (Chrome) because the tools are superior IMO. If you're getting into a situation where `1 > 5` then something is obviously not working. I would stop debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio. If you're not satisfied with that, then submit a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Not sure how this has to do with jQuery behavior?

Comment: It's more likely that you are misinterpreting results than vs or some browser is incorrectly evaluating `1>5`.

Comment: Did you try to close the file and reopen to make sure it is not some sort of cache issue?

Comment: I will reboot my computer and run this using VS2015 and will update.

Comment: Visual Studio has a habit where it shows the line that the code is running on.  If the code has changed since then, then it will still show the correct line (line 31) that's running, but line 31 no longer matches what you see in the editor so it looks like it's running the wrong code.  Hard-refresh the page (control-F5) and/or use browser console to disable cache.

Comment: Get some sleep, go outside for a jog, take a shower and come back to this. I swear it will make sense after some sleep.

Comment: @ epascarello then how do you explain 1<5

Comment: @ Benjamin Gruenbaum if it makes sense to you and you have some explanation then I invite you to provide a valid answer. Otherwise, put some rants will not help.

Comment: @SNash 1 is in fact less than 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours I finally found the reason :

1: In `VS2015` code works as expected

2: In `VS2017` statement `if (1>5)` gets resolved to true!!! (Pay attention to space after if

3: in `VS2017` statement `if(1>5)` works as Expected!

Now I'm convinced this is VS2017 bug.

Reference: **mozilla.org**
A whitespace character is an empty space (without any visual representation) on screen. Examples of whitespace characters include space characters, tabs, and line break characters. In JavaScript, the use of excessive whitespace is ignored.

==========

Update: to make things worst, statement 2 above behaves intermitently.